# Сети у нас есть, или SETI?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, idioms

Дорогая передача!

I must confess that until recently I never read any of Vysotsky in print. Doing so for the first time I've stumbled upon these lines, and I was immensely surprised.

As far as I understand, in

```
   Но на происки и бредни
   Сети есть у нас, и бредни
```

the word `Сети` is absolutely artificial and makes no sense. I bet he meant [SETI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_for_extraterrestrial_intelligence), as in `Search for Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence`.

The question is, is there an authoritative manuscript of this poem?

С уваженьем. Дата, подпись.

Comment: Перед "и" не нужна запятая (и её нет в тексте песни - http://www.kulichki.com/vv/pesni/dorogaya-peredacha-v-tu.html).

Comment: never use  BING translator on Russian text. that's horrendous algorithm that does not distinguish between homonyms (homophones in this case) neither never analyses structure

Comment: Vysotsky died in 1980, four years before SETI institute was founded.

Comment: @Abakan True, but the term was around since at least 1971, and became truly popular in 1977.

Comment: "SETI program" had been used since 1976 (see google ngrams), and the song had been written in 1977.

Comment: I can add some anecdotal evidence...  In the 90-s I worked with Venda Publishing which printed 8 volumes of Vysotsky's works and letters in 1994.  The texts were typed by someone who was employed by Vysotsky's museum in Moscow (e.g. used internal access to archives). That edition used the word "сети" in lower case, meaning fishing nets.

Answer (score 10):

There is a word play.

> `Но на происки и бредни` — `For intrigues and ravings`.
>
> `Сети есть у нас, и бредни` — `We have nets and drag-nets`.

In the first line `бредни` (from `бред` — *delirium*) means *silly twaddle, ravings*, while in the second line it's about fisherman tackles: [сеть](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) (*net*) and [бредень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C) (*drag-net*), which figurative can be used by authors of the letter to fight with that fraud.

Comment: By the way, the authors of the "letter" are patients of "Kanatchikova dacha" which is the famous Moscow asylum (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Московская_психиатрическая_больница_№_1).

Comment: first происки here are in meaning of *deceptions*, second one - *intrigues* (of enemies)

Comment: @artptr I am fluent enough in Russian to know that all. My understanding is that _SETI_ instead of _сети_ adds another dimension to this (beautiful) play. That is why I am after the manuscript.

Answer (score 2):

In Soviet times, foreign organization names would likely be translated into Russian and then abbreviated by their Russian name. For example, `International Atomic Energy Agency (IAEA)` is still `МАГАТЭ` in Russian.

So even if SETI is to be referenced in this song, it would probably be `Поиск Внеземного Разума` and not `СЕТИ`.

Comment: yet, *программа СЕТИ* or *программа SETI* has been popularized and is used in this very form in Russian, same as *НАТО, СЕНТО, СЕАТО, ЮНЕСКО, ЮНИСЕФ* etc.

Answer (score 1):

A fair warning, that poem slowly descends into nonsense genre toward end, so it is really hard to understand (did you tried to understand  *The Hunting of the Snark*?)

***Сети*** It's сеть  (eng. net) in plural form. By the way other synonyms, like  network  shall be translated as сеть too,  but in this case author meant fisherman's net.

Other word is homgraphic\homophonic pun.

1) plural **бредни**, singular **бредня**  in meaning of *twaddle*, *ravings*, *nonsense*. By it's own source, that word is a pun that became a dictionary word, a natural portmanteau of  бред — *delirium* and verbs *брести* - wade, wander, *забрести* -  to become disoriented.
2) **бредни** as plural of бредень - *drag-net*.

By the way it is a very complex, informal slang filled poem:

```
Дорогая передача! Во субботу, чуть не плача,
Вся Канатчикова дача к телевизору рвалась,
Вместо чтоб поесть, помыться у колодца и забыться,
Вся безумная больница у экрана собралась.

Говорил, ломая руки, краснобай и баламут
Про бессилие науки перед тайною Бермуд,
Все мозги разбил на части, все извилины заплел,
И канатчиковы власти колят нам второй укол.

Уважаемый редактор, может лучше про реактор, а?
Про любимый лунный трактор? Ведь нельзя же, год подряд
То тарелками пугают, дескать, подлые, летают,
То у вас собаки лают, то у вас руины говорят.

Мы кое в чем поднаторели, мы тарелки бьем весь год
Мы на них уже собаку съели, если повар нам не врет,
А медикаментов груды мы в унитаз, кто не дурак,
Вот это жизнь, а вдруг Бермуды. Вот те раз. Нельзя же так!

Мы не сделали скандала, нам вождя недоставало.
Настоящих буйных мало, вот и нету вожаков.
Но на происки и бредни сети есть у нас и бредни,
И не испортят нам обедни злые происки врагов.

Это их худые черти бермутят воду во пруду,
Это все придумал Черчиль в восемнадцатом году.
Мы про взрывы, про пожары сочиняли ноту ТАСС,
Тут примчались санитары и зафиксировали нас.

Тех, кто был особо боек, прикрутили к спинкам коек.
Бился в пене параноик, как ведьмак на шабаше:
"Развяжите полотенцы, иноверы, изуверцы.
Нам бермуторно на сердце и бермутно на душе".

Сорок душ посменно воют, раскалились добела.
Вот как сильно беспокоят треугольные дела,
Все почти с ума свихнулись, даже кто безумен был,
И тогда главврач Маргулис телевизор запретил.

Вон он, змей, в окне маячит, за спиною штепсель прячет
Подал знак кому-то, значит: "Фельдшер, вырви провода".
И нам осталось уколоться и упасть на дно колодца,
И там пропасть на дне колодца, как в Бермудах - навсегда.

Ну а завтра спросят дети, навещая нас с утра:
"Папы, что сказали эти кандидаты в доктора?"
Мы ответим нашим чадам правду - им не все равно,
Удивительное рядом, но оно - запрещено.

А вон дантист-надомник, Рудик,у него приемник "Грюндиг"
Он его ночами крутит, ловит, контра, ФРГ
Он там был купцом по шмуткам и подвинулся рассудком,
А к нам попал в волненьи жутком и с растревоженным
Желудком, и с номерочком на ноге.

Он прибежал взволнован крайне и сообщеньем нас потряс,
Будто наш уже научный лайнер в треугольнике погряз.
Сгинул, топливо истратив, весь распался на куски,
Но двух безумных наших братьев подобрали рыбаки.

Те, кто выжил в катаклизме, пребывают в пессимизме,
Их вчера в стеклянной призме к нам в больницу привезли.
И один из них, механик, рассказал, сбежав от нянек,
Что бермудский многогранник - незакрытый пуп земли.

Что там было, как ты спасся? Каждый лез и приставал,
Но механик только трясся и чинарики стрелял.
Он то плакал, то смеялся, то щетинился как еж,
Он над нами издевался. Ну сумасшедший, что возьмешь?

Взвился бывший алкоголик, матерщинник и крамольник,
Говорит: "Надо выпить треугольник. На троих его, даешь!"
Разошелся - так и сыплет: "Треугольник будет выпит.
Будь он параллелепипед, будь он круг, едрена вошь!"

Пусть безумная идея - не решайте сгоряча,
Отвечайте нам скорее через доку главврача.
С уваженьем, дата, подпись. Отвечайте нам, а то,
Если вы не отзоветесь мы напишем в "Спортлото".
```

A rare sound record  of it sung by author: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nmy0HGq0iSY

About verse you was looking at:

```
Мы не сделали скандала, нам вождя недоставало.
Настоящих буйных мало, вот и нету вожаков.
Но на происки и бредни сети есть у нас и бредни,
И не испортят нам обедни злые происки врагов.
```

**Мы не сделали скандала** - literally, *we didn't created a scandal*.  It's an idiom suggesting *"We didn't produced anything sensational*". нам вождя недоставало - we lacked a leader (chief). Настоящих буйных мало, вот и нету вожаков -  a compound elliptic phrase, *real mad people are rare, thus no leader(alpha) (present)* First line uses *вождь* (political leader, chief), second line uses *вожак* which may be attributed to *leader of the pack*, e.g. alpha wolf, but also can be used  in meaning of *leader*. Kind of rebellious suggestion that one should be truly mad to be a leader :P

Next verse: **бермутят** - portmanteau of *Bermuda* and **мутить** - *to roil*.

Later in text you'll find: **иноверы, изуверцы**. That's not dictionary words, it's a pun, based on mangling words together, creating two portmanteau words. Original words are изуверы (pl. of *изувер* - extremely cruel person, old meaning - religious fanatic) and иноверцы (pl. of *иноверец* - people of different religion, infidels).

One of most obscure jokes here is that they have lead doctor by last name **Марголис**. At same time patients supposedly are overreacting (hence this "letter" is written) to the documentary series directed and presented by *Марголис, Александр Давидович*, who was kind of celebrity in USSR. Title of series **Очевидное невероятное** (Obviously impossible) became a common term to describe some discussions related to paranormal mysteries.

**и с номерочком на ноге** - with a tag on foot. Curiously, tags  attached to foot only after triage  in field hospital (marking hopeless patients) or to already dead patient, e.g. in morgue.
**Канатчикова дача** - unofficial name of psychiatric asylum №1 in Moscow
"**Спортлото**" - totalizator that had TV representation in USSR.

Comment: _The Hunting of the Snark_ is a good reference point indeed. The difference is that Carroll invents the nonsense, whereas Vysotsky knew the reality of the ward first hand. Equally I don't think the song is along the lines of Хармс absurdity; it is rather a brilliant (almost clinical) parody to a viscous schizophrenic mindset. PS: I seriously doubt that изувер means sadist; I suppose it is more about one who lost the faith, изуверился. PPS: I have a positive score against Спортлото!

Comment: In the third line of the song, there apparently should be not "у колодца", but "уколоться" (to get an injection of psychotropic drug).

Comment: @user58697, "изувер" originally meaned "religious fanatic", but later broadened its meaning to "extremely and unreasonably cruel person". And Vysotsky manuscripts seem to be not so easy to find online. At least, I failed to find this song. I've no better ideas than to contact Vysotsky museum in Moscow http://www.visotsky.ru/kontakty. Probably, they have this manuscript in their collection.

Comment: @Lara good point about изуверы. Nonsense can get many forms, and another reason why compared poem to Carrol's that there are references and in-jokes which cannot be understood without having knowledge of context. Among features of nonsense here, no one actually would allow patients to watch questionable shows (may be no TV all is allowed). Whole ward is actually a metaphor.

Comment: @Lara I had vinyl disc that got same text on cover. But I bet that it is a cheat by homophonic pun (you know, censorship)  and he meant exactly that.

Comment: @Swift, I'm not sure about Kanatchikova Dacha in USSR times, but at least in some psychiatric hospitals nowadays there is a TV set in the dining room, showing federal channels. So, it's possible that the patients could really see that show, especially if it was popular among general public, including the hospital stuff...

Comment: @Lara when it is written, 1975 year? there is one of 1000 houses had TV , heh, and to get one, you had to  sign in your passport  into queue to get at TV set :P We received our first TV in 1985 early , only because grandma was working at rocket plant (one that makes Protons now)

Comment: @Swift, well, then you should be right)

Answer (score 1):

Я хочу добавить, что тут отсылка к выражению "прочесывать/проходить/ловить частым/широким/мелким бреднем". Примеры:

`Наловили мелким бреднем. Призыв в армию Таджикистана перевыполнен`  - заголовок статьи об успешном призыве в армию Таджикистана

`Мелким бреднем по «мелким» взяточникам` - заголовок статьи об арестах мелких взяточников.

`Широким бреднем. Назарбаев предложил создать "Мировую сеть по борьбе с терроризмом"` - заголовок статьи об инициативе Нурсултана Назарбаева по борьбе с терроризмом.

`Ловля лохов частым бреднем.` - заголовок статьи в блоге о сомнительной страховой компании.

Бредень в русском языке - метафорический инструмент, которым кого-то ловят (в приведённых примерах - лохов, призывников, террористов, взяточников).  Рыболовные сети - другой метафорический инструмент для примерно того же: есть выражения вроде "попасться в чьи-то сети", "широко раскинуть сети".